# nginx redirect to external folder

Tags: nginx

This is my nginx vhost conf:

```
upstream demo {
    server 127.0.0.1:9002 max_fails=250 fail_timeout=180s;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /home/web/public;

    location /demo/ {
        proxy_pass http://demo/;
    }

    location /demo/assets/ {
        #this is where I need to point localhost/demo/assets (and all of it's subfolders) to another folder
        #the line below obviously doesn't work
        root /home/user/Workspaces/demo/public;
    }

}
```

The root folder is pointing to `/home/web/public`, but I need the url `localhost/demo/assets/` and all of it's subfolders to go to another (external) folder. How do I do that?

I'm running nginx 1.4.3

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) directive, as well as read [the docs](http://nginx.org/r/root). Just a quote from it:

> A path to the file is constructed by merely adding a URI to the value of the **root** directive. If a URI has to be modified, the **alias** directive should be used.

Example:

```
location /demo/assets/ {
    alias /home/user/Workspaces/demo/public/;
}
```